# Missing Link -- which one, 7.3mm or 7.1mm?

Tags: chain, repair

KMC has two versions of their Missing Link, one that is 7.3mm and one that is 7.1mm. Both are advertised for 6/7/8 speed.

[image]

The only difference appears to be the pin length, but it's unclear if you had a non-SRAM/KMC chain, what you'd measure to make sure you got the right chain.

How can you measure -- or otherwise tell -- which Missing Link you should get?

Comment: Ahh... for the days when 3/32" was 3/32". :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the box that your chain came in -- 6/7/8 speed chains will either be 7.1 mm or 7.3 mm pin length.

The SRAM chains are 7.1 and Shimano are 7.3. KMC notes this on their [website](http://www.kmcchain.eu/connector-touring_city). Get the one that matches your chain brand (and if its KMC, get the one KMC suggests). Wipperman's lineup seems to be a mess -- some of the 8 speed are 6.6, others are 7.2; it might just be an error on their website though.

[image: Compatibility Chart]

The 7.3 mm missing link is known as the "KMC MissingLink I" and the 7.1 mm one is the "KMC MissingLink II". The 9's are 6.6 mm and the 10's are 5.9mm (which may be useful for someone who is confused with a higher speed chain, or another manufacturer's chain).

In practice, a lot of people use another manufacturer's quick link (KMC/Wipperman/SRAM) with another manufacturer's chain. I've used SRAM 8 speed Powerlinks in Shimano chains without problem. However, official manufacturer guidelines is generally to use their link closing method -- Shimano, use their special rivet, SRAM use the provided Powerlink/lock(for >9 speed), KMC is usually links, etc. But, normally, you get a link with the chain, and carry whatever link for emergencies; any of the links on the market for the right number of speeds will do for emergency repairs.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that compatibility chart. What a mess!  (also: hope you don't mind I copied an image of the compatibility chart into your answer for posterity).

Comment: thanks, Batman!